# how to use libraries inside my own class in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to implement a class that can handle numbers that are arbitrarily large. I know i can use other libraries like BigInteger but i just wanted to implement my own thing as practice.

My header file:

```
#ifndef INT_H
#define INT_H

//#ifndef vector
#include <vector>

class Int{
private:
    vector<int> v;
public:
    Int();
    Int(int);
    void clear();
    void push_back();
    void resize();
    vector<int>::iterator begin();
    vector<int>::iterator end();
    int size();
    void sum(Int &, Int, Int);
    void sub(Int &, Int, Int);
    void prod(Int &, Int, Int);
    Int operator+(const Int &);
    Int operator-(const Int &);
    Int operator*(const Int &);
    Int operator>(Int &);
    Int operator<(Int &);
    Int operator>=(Int &);
    Int operator<=(Int &);
    int& operator[] (Int);
};

//#endif // vector
#endif // INT_H
```

The problem is it gives me an error on the first encounter of vector on line 9, namely "expected unqualified-id before '<' token"

Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit: Confused define with include.
Now i get vector does not name a type

Comment: Do you really think it has anything to do with the fact that you're trying to write a big integer class?

Comment: Change all instances of `vector` to `std::vector`.

Comment: ... or write `using namespace std;`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov [Please don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It would be much better to do `using std::vector;` if you really can't change all instances

Comment: @RyanBemrose I agree, your option is better. But there is usually no problems with `using namespace ... ` in cpp files.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) answer to understand what sort of problems may crop up with the `using namespace blah` idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vector` type from [`#include <vector>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is in the `std` namespace; since the explicit type of `vector<int>` is not defined in your code, you need to do one of the following to fix this issue:

1. Rename all instances of `vector<T>` to `std::vector<T>` where `T` is the type the vector will contain (in your case an `int`).

or

2. After `#include <vector>` you need to add the line `using std::vector;`. With this [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations), anywhere an unqualified `vector` type is encountered, it will use the `std::vector` type.

Remember, since this class is defined in a header, if you use option 2, then anywhere you `#include "Int.h"`, you're also including a `using std::vector;` declaration.

A side note to your code: I'm not sure what your full intent with your `Int` class will be, especially since your class offers member functions that resemble a sequence container, but don't forget your [assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) (e.g. `Int& operator=(std::uint32_t i) ...`).

Hope that can help.